# How can I use NID Token with the Insert Module?

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I have setup insert module to upload images in a body field.
I want to set the path for the "FILE DIRECTORY" to the "node id" token but it does not show in the avaliable tokens.

The image field looks like
[image]

Browse avaliable tokens looks like
[image]

Why isn't the nid token available?

Comment: Which nid are you looking for - the one for the image file or the one for the page you are trying to create?

Comment: The one for the page that the image is used on. - I Tried content-type/[site:current-page:nid] . But doesn't work

Comment: where is the above token dialogue coming from? and you are trying to control the path that the image gets uploaded to, not the path gets output in the display, correct?

Comment: The tokens come from the link below the helper text. Yes i want to set the upload path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [filefields_path](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module to add node tokens to your imagefield (or any other file fields):

> The File (Field) Paths module extends the default functionality of
>   Drupal's core Upload module, the FileField module and many other File
>   Upload modules by adding the ability to use node tokens in destination
>   paths and filenames.

In my test environment with the insert module and this module enabled, I now have the capacity to use node:nid in the filefield path as well as a number of other useful tokens:

[image]